# Box Select using leaflet by modifying box zoom with turf intersect

Tags: postgis, leaflet, turf

I have been trying to select multiple polygons using box select. I have modified box zoom for this purpose and included turf.js for intersect function. The problem is if i select a particular area and use interset function it shows polygons from different area. If i select two polygons it show four polygons from another area.below is my code

Tried postgis intersection, bounds intersect in leaflet, turf intersect all results in same.

Note - geojson data contains 7000 polygons.

```
 $(function() {
        L.Map.BoxZoom.prototype._onMouseUp = function (e) {
            this._finish();

            if (!this._moved) { return; }

             var nw = this._map.layerPointToLatLng(this._startLayerPoint);
            var se = this._map.layerPointToLatLng(this._map.mouseEventToContainerPoint(e));
            var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(nw,se);
            getparcels(bounds);
        }
    })

function getparcels(bounds) {
       var geodata = L.rectangle(bounds).toGeoJSON();
       geojsonlayer = L.geoJson(Data, {
          onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
              try{
                if(turf.intersect(geodata,feature)){
                   layer.setStyle({
                      fillColor: 'black',
                      fillOpacity: 0.3
                   })
                   map.addLayer(layer)
                 }
                }catch (e) {
                   console.log(e)
                 }
          }
     })
}
```

need a function to select multiple polygons by box-selections

Comment: Formally it looks OK. Did you try to debug and step through layer selection to find out why wrong layer is selected as being intersected?

Comment: It's hard to know what "another area" exactly means without seeing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)